# M2Crypto: AttributeError for load_dynamic_engine()

Tags: python, openssl, m2crypto

I am using M2Crypto-0.20.2.  I want to use engine_pkcs11 from the OpenSC project and the Aladdin PKI client for token based authentication making xmlrpc calls over ssl.

I am trying to load the PKCS#11 engine as well as the Aladdin module (see code below).  But I get an error:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'load_dynamic_engine'

```
from M2Crypto import SSL, m2
m2.load_dynamic_engine("dynamic","/usr/local/ssl/lib/engines/engine_pkcs11.so")
m2.load_dynamic_engine("pkcs11","/usr/lib/libeTPkcs11.so")
```

According to the M2Crypto documentation, this function should be available.  This is the documentation I'm reading:  http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/m2crypto/api/

Can anyone point me to the correct documentation or help with figuring out how to load the engines?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used the Engine module myself, so I cannot give you any definite answers. However, you should take a look at [test_engine.py](http://svn.osafoundation.org/m2crypto/trunk/tests/test_engine.py) module for some pointers. I am guessing that to load engines provided by OpenSSL you shouldn't use that form of `load_dynamic_engine()`, but either `load_dynamic()` or `load_openssl()`. You'd probably need `load_dynamic_engine()` only when loading 3rd party modules.

Comment: Thank you.  load_dynamic() is working for engine_pkcs11 engine.

Answer (score 0):

I was reading the documentation wrong.  The load_dynamic_engine() belong in the Engine module.

I changed the command and now get a different error:
Engine.load_dynamic_engine("dynamic","/usr/local/ssl/lib/engines/engine_pkcs11.so")

bad engine id
Engine.load_dynamic_engine("dynamic","/usr/local/ssl/lib/engines/engine_pkcs11.so")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.4/site-packages/M2Crypto/Engine.py", line 92, in load_dynamic_engine
    e.ctrl_cmd_string("LOAD", None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.4/site-packages/M2Crypto/Engine.py", line 38, in ctrl_cmd_string
    raise EngineError(Err.get_error())
M2Crypto.Engine.EngineError: 23541:error:260B606D:engine routines:DYNAMIC_LOAD:init failed:eng_dyn.c:521:

Any idea what this means?